# Hive query to get expected output

Tags: hive

I am new to hive. I got a requirement to build a query. I have table with 3 columns(ENO, ENAME, LOCATION)

```
ENO, ENAME, LOCATION
001, XYZ, HYD
002, ABC, MU
```

I need output like below.

```
001, XYZ, H
001, XYZ, Y
001, XYZ, D
002, ABC, M
002, ABC, U
```

This is output  am looking for any one have idea to get this.

Thanks,
Ranjith

Answer (score 0):

Split the string in the 3rd column and use explode to convert the column array values into rows.

```
select * from
(
   select 
     ENO, 
     ENAME,
     lateral view explode(split(LOCATION,'')) AS LOCATION
   from
     table_name
 )
 where LOCATION != '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `explode` command along with `split` to achieve the above result.

Query:

```
SELECT ENO,ENAME,SPLIT_LOC FROM <TABLE NAME> LATERAL VIEW explode(split(LOCATION,'')) EXPLOCATION AS SPLIT_LOC
```

splitting the LOCATION with `''` will split your data per character.

Hope this helps :)